# cakephp open image browsing window on clicking a text

Tags: image, forms, cakephp

I am new to coding. I am working on a cakephp image gallery app where images will be kept on specified albums. Here I am trying to upload an image  where the image browse window should open wen clicked on a text or a box..much like the facebook.
Here is something i tried:

```
<div class="photo_upload_thumbnail">
        <div id="thumbnail_text">
 <?php 
          echo $this->Html->link('+Add Album',array('controller'=> 'albums','actions'=>'upload')); ?>
                 </div>
      </div>
```

upload.ctp:

```
<?php  echo $this->Form->create('Photo',array('type'=>'file')); ?>
<div class="form_row" >
<?php           $this->Form->input('image', array('type' => 'file'));?>
</div>
        <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **'target' => '_blank'** to open in new tab

Change

```
<div class="photo_upload_thumbnail">
        <div id="thumbnail_text">
 <?php 
          echo $this->Html->link('+Add Album',array('controller'=> 'albums','actions'=>'upload')); ?>
                 </div>
      </div>
```

to

```
<div class="photo_upload_thumbnail">
        <div id="thumbnail_text">
 <?php 
          echo $this->Html->link('+Add Album',array('controller'=> 'albums','action'=>'upload'),array('target' => '_blank')); ?>
                 </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not working. as earlier the url routes to /actions:upload/target:_blank

Comment: mmmm, why is 'actions' instead 'action'?

Answer (score 0):

In upload.ctp, add an "echo" to the image input field; it should read as follows:

```
echo $this->Form->input('image', array('type' => 'file'));
```

You omitted the echo so you cannot see the input field